# Completing a function to add Values depending on specific "Regions" (More info provided)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

I have two files, one containing over 200 tweets, and another containing key words and values. a typical tweet looks like: (I also provided my code below)

```
[41.923916200000001, -88.777469199999999] 6 2011-08-28 19:24:18 My life is a moviee. ( only the number in brackets and the words after the time are relevant)
```

and the keywords look something like

```
love,10
like,5
best,10
hate,1
```

With the two numbers at the beginning of the tweet, I use that to determine what region the tweet was made in (shown below in my code). & For each individual tweet (each line in the file), depending on the number of keywords in the tweet, I add them, divided by the total of values associated with them (per tweet) which gives me the score. **My question is, how would I be able to total the scores for all the tweets in a region and divide that by the number of tweets in that region?** Below, where I put happynessTweetScore, is how I calculated the score for the individual tweets in the file (each line) that actually contain keywords. **For this part, I'm not sure how to add all the values depending on the region, and divide them depending on the number of tweets in that region? like should I add them to a list depending on their region then add?? i don't know.**
***I started it like this:***

```
def score(tweet):
    total = 0  
    total_value = 0  
    for word in tweet:
        if word in sentiments:
            total_value += sentiments[word]  
            total_count += 1                
    return total_value, total_count
```

But I dont know how to use SOMETHING like this in order to total the scores for all of the tweets in each region indivdually and divide that by the number of tweets in that region?

I divided the tweets into four regions (latitude, long) using these values (rectangle) ALL THE WAY at the bottom of the code:

```
p1 = (49.189787, -67.444574) 
p2 = (24.660845, -67.444574) 
p3 = (49.189787, -87.518395) 
p4 = (24.660845, -87.518395) 
p5 = (49.189787, -101.998892) 
p6 = (24.660845, -101.998892) 
p7 = (49.189787, -115.236428)
p8 = (24.660845, -115.236428) 
p9 = (49.189787, -125.242264)
p10 = (24.660845, -125.242264) 

from collections import Counter
try:
    keyW_Path = input("Enter file named keywords: ")
    keyFile = open(keyW_Path, "r")
except IOError:
    print("Error: file not found.")
    exit()
# Read the keywords into a list
keywords = {}
wordFile = open('keywords.txt', 'r')
for line in wordFile.readlines():
    word = line.replace('\n', '')
    if not(word in keywords.keys()): #Checks that the word doesn't already exist.
        keywords[word] = 0 # Adds the word to the DB.
wordFile.close()
# Read the file name from the user and open the file.
try:
    tweet_path = input("Enter file named tweets: ")
    tweetFile = open(tweet_path, "r")
except IOError:
    print("Error: file not found.")
    exit()
#Calculating Sentiment Values
with open('keywords.txt') as f:
    sentiments = {word: int(value) for word, value in (line.split(",") for line in f)}

with open('tweets.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = Counter(word for word in line.split() if word in sentiments)
        if not values:
            continue
keyW = ["love", "like", "best", "hate", "lol", "better", "worst", "good", "happy", "haha", "please", "great", "bad", "save", "saved", "pretty", "greatest", 'excited', 'tired', 'thanks', 'amazing', 'glad', 'ruined', 'negative', 'loving', 'sorry', 'hurt', 'alone', 'sad', 'positive', 'regrets', 'God']
with open('tweets.txt') as oldfile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if any(word in line for word in keyW):
            newfile.write(line)
def score(tweet):
    total = 0
    for word in tweet:
        if word in sentiments:
            total += 1
    return total
def total(score):
    sum = 0
    for number in score:
        if number in values:
            sum += 1
#Classifying the regions
class Region:
    def __init__(self, lat_range, long_range):
        self.lat_range = lat_range
        self.long_range = long_range
    def contains(self, lat, long):
        return self.lat_range[0] <= lat and lat < self.lat_range[1] and\
               self.long_range[0] <= long and long < self.long_range[1]
eastern = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-87.518395, -67.444574))
central = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-101.998892, -87.518395))
mountain = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-115.236428, -101.998892))
pacific = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-125.242264, -115.236428))

eastScore = 0
centralScore = 0
pacificScore = 0
mountainScore = 0
happyScoreE = 0

for line in open('newfile.txt'):
    line = line.split(" ")
    lat = float(line[0][1:-1]) #Stripping the [ and the ,
    long = float(line[1][:-1])  #Stripping the ]
    if eastern.contains(lat, long):
        eastScore += score(line)
    elif central.contains(lat, long):
        centralScore += score(line)
    elif mountain.contains(lat, long):
        mountainScore += score(line)
    elif pacific.contains(lat, long):
        pacificScore += score(line)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Could you edit your title to be more specific? I really couldn't get the gist of your question by reading the title.

Comment: Ok @ Leaf I will!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say - as you said, we have the file containting the data like:

```
love,10
movie,5
```

First of all, create the dictionary from the file.

```
kw_to_score = {}
kw_file = 'keywords.txt'
with open(kw_file, 'r') as kwf:
    for line in kwf.readlines():
       word, score = line.split(',')
       kw_to_score[word] = int(score)
```

One we done it, we need to create the score function:

```
def score(tweet, keywords):
    score = 0
    count = 0
    for word in tweet.split(): # split words by spaces
        if word in keywords:
           score += keywords[word]
           count += 1
    return score, count
```

After that, continue..

```
class Region:
    def __init__(self, lat_range, long_range):
        self.lat_range = lat_range
        self.long_range = long_range
        self.score = 0 # add new field
        self.quantity = 0 # add new field
    def contains(self, lat, long):
        return self.lat_range[0] <= lat and lat < self.lat_range[1] and\
               self.long_range[0] <= long and long < self.long_range[1]

eastern = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-87.518395, -67.444574))
central = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-101.998892, -87.518395))
mountain = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-115.236428, -101.998892))
pacific = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-125.242264, -115.236428))


for line in open('newfile.txt'):
    line = line.split(" ")
    lat = float(line[0][1:-1]) #Stripping the [ and the ,
    long = float(line[1][:-1])  #Stripping the ]
    for region in (eastern, central, mountain, pacific):
        if region.contains(lat, long):
            region_score, count = score(line, kw_to_score) # pass the extra dict with keywords mapped to score
            region.score += region_score
            region.quantity += count
```

Then all you need to do is just go for:

```
print(eastern.score / eastern.quantity) # That would give you the avg.
```

Comment: score, count = score(line) # assume that score returns the score and counts words  this line raises a TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: I've done editing to my post, so u can check it now.

Comment: score += kewyords[word] for this line, the keywords if underlined saying unresolved reference

Comment: and for for line in wordFile.readlines(): the .readlines says unresolved attribute reference

Comment: The first one was a typo `kewyords` instead `keywords`, and the 2nd one is not from my code. Im not providing you the full solution, saying that you just have to copy-paste it all, but showing you better way to go. First part of the code u can use to get the dict from file. Then, the 2nd one will take created dict and line from the 'newfile.txt' file object and then, it will check the region to which it belongs in the last part, and count the words. I assume that the 'newfile.txt' contains lines like `[41.923916200000001, -88.777469199999999] 6 2011-08-28 19:24:18 My life is a moviee.`

Comment: Ok I will try this out and get back to you, thank you so much!

Comment: u see how you did def score(tweet, keywords):
    score = 0
    count = 0
    for word in tweet.split(): # split words by spaces
        if word in keywords:
           score += keywords[word]
           count += 1
    return score, count is it any different doing them separate? or no

Comment: My function returns a tuple containing `(score, count)` values, which allows me to use `score, count = score(line, kw_to_score)`. However if you create two different functions (one to count, and other to add the score), just use them separately like `score = count_score(line), count = count_coung(line)` or whatever your functions are called.

Comment: Im not copying word for word, I'm comparing it side to side with my code and looking for ways to make improvements! but Yea I figured that part out,  but Im confused about one part you did, this line score, count = score(line, kw_to_score) raises TypeError: 'int' object is not callable @Nf4r

Comment: That's also my bad. Just do not use the same name for variables as for the functions. Change the `score` variable to any other, like `region_score` to not overwrite the `score` function.

Comment: Lol, so close to finishing the code just two more lines! for this line region.score += score raises TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'function' which I think will do for the next line as well since its region.quantity += count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128393/discussion-between-nf4r-and-helloworld4382).

Answer (score 0):

You could try throwing it in a dictionary where the key is the region and the value is an array of the scores for that region. That way the data and the ability to manipulate it will be easily accessible.

EDIT:
You can just make it part of the object actually and your code will be cleaner something like this. I haven't had a chance to test it but it should provide a foundation for you to work off of

```
class Region:
score = []
def __init__(self, lat_range, long_range):
    self.region_name = region_name
    self.lat_range = lat_range
def contains(self, lat, long):
    return self.lat_range[0] <= lat and lat < self.lat_range[1] and\
           self.long_range[0] <= long and long < self.long_range[1] 
def averageScore(self):
    return sum(self.score)/len(self.score)



for line in open('newfile.txt'):
line = line.split(" ")
lat = float(line[0][1:-1]) #Stripping the [ and the ,
long = float(line[1][:-1])  #Stripping the ]
if eastern.contains(lat, long):
    easter.score.append(score(line))
elif central.contains(lat, long):
    central.score.append(score(line))
elif mountain.contains(lat, long):
    mountain.score.append(score(line))
elif pacific.contains(lat, long):
    pacific.score.append(score(line))
```